# Find the number of distinct linearly dependent sets of the form $\{u,v\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

> Consider  $\Bbb Z_3$ the field with $3$ elements .Let $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_3$ be the vector space over $\Bbb Z_3$.
>
> Find the number of distinct linearly dependent sets of the form $\{u,v\}$ where $u,v\in \Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_3\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

My try:

If  $\{u,v\}$ is linearly dependent then $u=av$ for some $a\in \Bbb Z_3$.

Then the possible options are $\,\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\}.$ So it will be $3$ .But the answer given is $4$ .Where am I wrong?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly found the 2-element linearly dependent subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_3$.  But that's not what the problem asks for: it asks for linearly dependent 2-element subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.  So $u$ and $v$ should each be an ordered pair of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (different from $(0,0)$).

(Also, the problem statement is slightly incorrect: it should also require that $u\neq v$.)

Comment: Thank you so much Now I got $4$

Comment: i got 8 as an answer why is it 4?

Comment: @Upstart: You're probably counting ordered pairs $(u,v)$ instead of sets.

Comment: if the {($0,0$)} is included then i think it will be $8$

Comment: @EricWofsey,,,(1,0), (0,2),(0,1) and (2,0) here im getting   4,,,Is it correct or not ? pliz tell me

Comment: I am also stuck on $4$th set, found 3 which are $\{(0,1),(0,2)\}, \{(1,0),(2,0)\}, \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

Answer (score 0):

Fourth pair will be {(1,2),(2,1)} as (2,1)can be written by -1(1,2)=(-1,-2) and field is F3 or can say Z3 and in Z3 -1 is equivalent to 2 and -2 is equivalent to 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).